# org.json.JSONException: Value ... - volley?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am connecting to a url with volley in android :

```
private void connectToUrl(String url) {
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("d");
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.i("VALUEDSSDDD", object.getString("urlpic"));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Custom Log Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.i("ERRRROOORR",error.getMessage()+"");
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_arry);
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
}
```

But when I connect to `url` get me error :

```
org.json.JSONException: Value .....
```

Here is my `json` :

```
{
    "d": [{
        "apiCurrentUserID": 0,
        "apiCurrentUserName": null,
        "urlpic": "http://Image.jpg",
        "Title": "Jim",
        "FileMusicUrl": "http://video.mp4",
        "StringDuration": "05':07''",
        "ViewCount": 57,
        "DownloadCount": 56,
        "uploadDate": "/Date(1473550560)/",
        "MusicID": 192727,
        "UserID": 0,
        "Summary": "Some text",
        "OrderView": null,
        "ShowDate": "/Date(1473550500)/",
        "FileSize": "19.15 MB",
        "RatePlus": null,
        "RateDash": null,
        "ChannelID": 0,
        "ChannelName": null,
        "CurrentChannelID": 0,
        "CurrentChannelName": null,
        "isFollowed": false,
        "profileImgUserSend": null,
        "isDisliked": false,
        "isLiked": false,
        "isLatered": false,
        "isFavorited": false,
        "apiCategories": null,
        "apiTags": [{
            "tageID": "438232",
            "titleTag": "book"
        }, {
            "tageID": "411557",
            "titleTag": "sounds"
        }, {
            "tageID": "365984",
            "titleTag": "map"
        }]
     }],
    "RowwCount": 0
}
```

I am getting above `json` from `url` .

**EDIT :**

I edit my code to :

```
private void connectToUrl(String url) {
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        JSONObject contacts = jsonObj.getJSONObject("d");
                        try {
                            Log.i("VALUEDSSDDD", contacts.getString("urlpic"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", "Error " + error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(obreq);
}
```

But get me an error :

```
null
```

In the last code show me result but in this code don't any result.

Comment: Post Complete error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response that you have pasted is not a JSONArray it's a JSONObject. You need to get the value of d which is a JSON Array.

Comment: I used from JsonObjectRequest but get me Error null,don't get any result.

Comment: @ android_dev . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JoJoRoid Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved :

```
private void connectToUrl(String url) {
    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("d");
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Custom Log Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Log.i("ERRRROOORR",error.getMessage()+"");
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_arry);
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
}
```